# JBoss AS 4.2.3 Hot deploy Exploded files

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I have an issue hot deploying on JBoss Application Server 4.2.3.GA. The server does not redeploy the application when i update the `web.xml` file. Is it that only classes changed will make the server to redploy the application? If this is the case how do I redeploy non-class files?

Please advice.

Thanks, Saquib

Answer (score 2):

JBoss redeploys the web application when it detects a change to the web.xml. 
Make sure that whatever you are using to modify this makes a change to the timestamp on the file. So

```
 touch web.xml
```

should be the charm for a redeploy

Answer (score 1):

If your application is expanded from an EAR, being the WAR a part of it, try updating the META-INF/application.xml file.